# Move a circle on mouse click

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paint, mouse-listeners

I am really new to Java and I need a circle to move around a JFrame when it's clicked, but the circle has to get random coordinates. So far this code generates a new circle every time it's clicked, but all the other circles stay there as well. I only need one circle to move around the frame. So maybe someone can help me a little :)

Here is my code:

```
public class test2 extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
int height, width;
public test2() {
    this.setTitle("Click");
    this.setSize(400,400);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    addMouseListener(this);
    width = getSize().width;
    height = getSize().height;
}

public void paint (Graphics g) {
    setBackground (Color.red);
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    int a, b;
    a = -50 + (int)(Math.random()*(width+40));
    b = (int)(Math.random()*(height+20));
    g.fillOval(a, b, 130, 110);
}

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int a, b;
    a = -50 + (int)(Math.random()*(width+40));
    b = (int)(Math.random()*(height+20));
    repaint();
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}

public static void main(String arg[]){

    new test2();
}

}
```

Comment: A word of advice, it's better to take advantage of double buffering provided by Swing. So instead of painting directly onto the JFrame, much wise would be to paint on a JPanel/JComponent by overridding the respective paintComponent(...) method.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: that tag is [obsolete](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if this helps, here i have filled the entire rect with background color before drawing the circle. Though not efficient but serves the purpose

replace the paint method as follows

```
public void paint (Graphics g) {
        setBackground (Color.red);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        int a, b;
        a = -50 + (int)(Math.random()*(width+40));
        b = (int)(Math.random()*(height+20));
        g.fillOval(a, b, 130, 110);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

i think one of the major problems you are having here is that you don't make global a and b variables. You create 2 new variables every time you call the `paint()` and `mouseClicked()` methods. There are two other problems/warnings.

1. Your `` `paint() `` method really should be called `paintComponents(Graphics g)` if you are using a `JFrame`
2. You need to add the line `super.paint(g);` under your paintComponents() definition.

I am actually quite surprised that anything is drawn at all. Also, Anony-Mousse is right when he says about conventions. Class names should always begin with a capital.

Your code should look like this:

```
public class Test2 extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
int height, width;
int a,b;
public test2() {
    this.setTitle("Click");
    this.setSize(400,400);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    addMouseListener(this);
    width = getSize().width;
    height = getSize().height;
}

public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    setBackground(Color.red);
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    a = -50 + (int)(Math.random()*(width+40));
    b = (int)(Math.random()*(height+20));
    g.fillOval(a, b, 130, 110);
}

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int a, b;
    a = -50 + (int)(Math.random()*(width+40));
    b = (int)(Math.random()*(height+20));
    repaint();
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}

public static void main(String arg[]){

    new test2();
}

}
```

Comment: +1 but I'd suggest that you (and the OP) use a JPanel or JComponent instead, for one, it provides double buffering, IMHO

Comment: Your right, of course, but i was focusing on the actual graphics rather than the screens.

Comment: Sorry, just an observation, not a criticism ;)

Comment: i know no worries :) i upvoted ur comment because it was something I didn't spot xD

Comment: Thanks for all the information, as I said I am new to Java and all the pointers are appreciated.

Comment: everyone has to start somewhere - a **really** great start would be accepting my answer xD